# how could we match the north angle of HMC5883-l compass with actual north angle

Tags: arduino, compass

I am developing a gps guided robot based on arduino, I am using hmc5883-l compass, I have calibrated the compass but the issue is that It shows direction wrong,for example if my robot has to travel west which is 270 degree, my robot will be doing corrections to match the 270 degrees but the 270 degrees of the robot is not actual 270 degree.

I am using this code

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <HMC5883L.h>

HMC5883L compass;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initialize HMC5883L");
  while (!compass.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid HMC5883L sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }

  compass.setRange(HMC5883L_RANGE_1_3GA);
  compass.setMeasurementMode(HMC5883L_CONTINOUS);
  compass.setDataRate(HMC5883L_DATARATE_30HZ);
  compass.setSamples(HMC5883L_SAMPLES_8);
  compass.setOffset(72,177);
}

void loop()
{
  Vector norm = compass.readNormalize();

  float heading = atan2(norm.YAxis, norm.XAxis);
  float declinationAngle = (2 + (8 / 60.0)) / (180 / M_PI);
  heading += declinationAngle;
  if (heading < 0)
  {
    heading += 2 * PI;
  }

  if (heading > 2 * PI)
  {
    heading -= 2 * PI;
  }
  float headingDegrees = heading * 180/M_PI; 
  Serial.print(" Heading = ");
  Serial.print(heading);
  headingDegrees=360-headingDegrees; //because compass is upside down
  Serial.print(" Degrees  = ");
  Serial.print(headingDegrees);


  Serial.println();

  delay(100);
}
```

Output while robot is pointing in the west direction(270 degree)

```
 Heading = 0.18 Degrees  = 349.68
 Heading = 0.17 Degrees  = 350.19
 Heading = 0.16 Degrees  = 350.74
 Heading = 0.19 Degrees  = 349.34
 Heading = 0.19 Degrees  = 349.22
 Heading = 0.17 Degrees  = 350.51
 Heading = 0.18 Degrees  = 349.66
 Heading = 0.18 Degrees  = 349.95
 Heading = 0.20 Degrees  = 348.71
 Heading = 0.16 Degrees  = 350.74
 Heading = 0.18 Degrees  = 349.90
 Heading = 0.19 Degrees  = 348.89
```

At this point the Degrees must be 270 but its around 348

Comment: 270 + 72 = 342 which is suspiciously close to the observed values, don't you think?

Comment: thanks for your reply, the issue has been solved